# QGIS Toolbox "Points to path" layer can not "make permanent", layer disappears after "make permanent" to CSV files

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

After I made permanent for the new path layer (with Points to path toolbox function), which is done by saving CSV files of the new path layer, the layer just disappears from the window, the checkbox also lost. Not sure what happens.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just used the defaults when you made it permanent, you didn't save the geometry to the CSV.

[image]

[image]

Instead, ensure you select "AS_WKT" to include the geometry in the output CSV.

[image]

[image]